# Best approach to using controllers in React

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, controller

I'm developing a React app and I'm having doubts on how to implement an *MVC-ish* architecture. The project structure is as follows

```
src/
|- models/
|- controllers/
|- components/
```

To manage the auth state of a user I'm using the
Context API, wrapping the root component in it, let's call it `UserContext`. React Router is used for routing, so the components hierarchy looks like this

```
UserContext
|- Router
   |- ...
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how I would make the controllers accessible to any components that might need them. As of now, still in the early stages of development, each controller method is a static one which doesn't sound too bad as there will never be 2 controllers of the same kind with different data

```
import ControllerA from '../controller/ControllerA';


ControllerA.methodB(...args);
```

But as I'm coming from an OOP background this doesn't sit well with me. What I'm contemplating to do is create a new Context, `ControllerContext` (?) which will store an instance of every controller and that will be consumed alongside `UserContext`.

```
const { controllerA } = this.controllerContext;

controllerA.methodB(...args);
```

I personally don't see any practical differences between these 2 approaches, only that the latter seems more MVC-like, but there's a big chance that I'm missing something. Which approach would you use (if any), and why is it better than the other?

Comment: Also coming from an OOP background to React.... you're going to have a bad time trying to force OOP patterns into React, React just works differently.

Comment: fair enough. I'll learn more about react specific patterns and try to refactor